# Get tab-pane content from result in an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm struggling in figuring out a way to get the content in one of my "tab-content" from an action other than my index

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                @Html.ActionLink("Analysis History", "Index", "Feedback", new { Tab = "Analysis" }, new { @class = "nav-link active" })
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                @Html.ActionLink("Pending Analysis Requests", "PendingList", "Feedback", new { Tab = "Pending" }, new { @class = "nav-link active" })
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade @(ViewBag.Hash == "Analysis" ? "show active" : "")" id="Analysis" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Analysis-tab">
                <div> .... </div> // WORKS FINE
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade @(ViewBag.Hash == "Pending" ? "show active" : "")" id="Pending" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Pending-tab">
                <div>
                    //HERE I WANT THE RESULT FROM PENDINGLIST ACTION
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Action

```
public async Task <IActionResult> PendingList (int AnalysisPage = 1, string Tab = "Pending")
        {
            ViewBag.Hash = Tab;
            //POPULATING THE MODEL

            return PartialView("_PendingAnlaysisRequestsList", model);
        }
```

_PendingAnlaysisRequestsList partial is holding a table to display model content

ps: in index action I'm setting ViewBag.Hash and the whole action returns view()

Is using ajax the only solution or is there any other ways ?

any suggestions is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I suggest you could use ajax and tab content to achieve your requirement, you could use ajax to load the view and generate the Hyperlink to show them.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Notice: You should replace the ajax url with your own url.

```
 <div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="Analysis" id="Analysislink"
                href="#Analysis">Analysis</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="Pending" id="Pendinglink"
               href="#Pending">Pending</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="Analysis" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Analysis-tab">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Pending" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Pending-tab">

    </div>
</div>




@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    
    <script>
          $("#Analysislink").click(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/StaffDetails?StaffID=@Model.StaffID",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Analysis").html(result);
                }
            })
            });


            $("#Pendinglink").click(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/Biodata",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Pending").html(result);
                }
            })
            });

        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Staff/Onboarding/StaffDetails?StaffID=@Model.StaffID",
                type: "get",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#Analysis").html(result);
                }
            })

        })
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much i appreciate your help!

Comment: If you feel my  reply has helped you, please mark it as answer so that other folks who faces the same issue could find the solution more easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it simply by the following modifications:

PendingList Action

```
public async Task <MyIndexModel> PendingList (int AnalysisPage, string Tab)
    {
        ViewBag.Hash = Tab;
        //POPULATING THE MODEL

        return model;
    }
```

Index Action:

```
            if(Tab == "Analysis")
            {
            //POPULATING THE MODEL WITH DEFFERENT DATA 
            }
            if(Tab == "Pending")
            {
                model = PendingList(AnalysisPage,Tab).Result;
            }
```

View:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            @Html.ActionLink("Analysis History", "Index", "Feedback", new { Tab = "Analysis" }, new { @class = "nav-link active" })
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            @Html.ActionLink("Pending Analysis Requests", "PendingList", "Feedback", new { Tab = "Pending" }, new { @class = "nav-link active" })
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade @(ViewBag.Hash == "Analysis" ? "show active" : "")" id="Analysis" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Analysis-tab">
            <div> .... </div> // WORKS FINE
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade @(ViewBag.Hash == "Pending" ? "show active" : "")" id="Pending" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Pending-tab">
            <div>
                //HERE I LISTED THE RESULT IN A TABLE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Best Regards